# How to list all articles on default search page?

Tags: theming

I am new to drupal, and trying to **get all articles on default search page** .i.e. when user has not yet entered any keyword to search, I want to show all articles by default.

I know I have to do something in `search-results.tpl.php` but not sure of how to do it.

Comment: No no no, don't use tpl files for receiving data. Also, consider views module. Is it really out of the question?

Comment: I haven't used views module but I just themed my  search-result.tpl.php for theming search result. So, thought of doing something with search-results.tpl.php to get all articles, no?

Comment: No. tpl.php is for templating. About how things look. Nothing else, nothing more. You should get deeper to change *data*.

Comment: For search results page, yes it was just templating, but can you explain how to get all articles on default page?

Comment: Nope, I can't. If I want more flexibility, I try to go with views.

Comment: Yeah, @molot is right. It's good to use Views and Search API together.